# Meaning of a Notation Symbol (

Tags: notation, jazz, saxophone

I wonder if anyone can tell me what the curved notation next to the 8th notes are. If it helps, this is a score for saxophone.

Thanks.

[image: Unknown Notation]

Comment: A nice check would be to listen to a recording of whatever it is - obviously if available.

Comment: Looking at the amount of discussion arising in the currently only answer, the question should deliver significantly more context: Style, period, name of the piece, composer just for the beginning.

Comment: @guidot The tags might give you a clue!  'Notation, jazz, saxophone'.

Answer (score 8):

It's a "scoop" or "slide". It means you bend into the note, starting a bit flat and then bending the note upward until it's in tune.

Typically, the symbol looks like ")" rather than "(".

[image: Example of standard scoop notation]

Comment: Probably all it can be, although a lift is a straight line rising and a scoop is a 'bracket' opposite to the direction here.

Comment: Is this notation used for saxophone or wind instruments only?

Comment: @user1079505 I know it because I've seen it for trumpet, so it applies to brass, but I don't know about, say, flute, or string instruments.

Comment: Not really how you write a scoop.  But yes, possibly a 'best attempt' in a rudimentary notation program.

Comment: @user1079505: I've seen it in guitar notation for when the bend is less than a half-step. This example I'd interpret as: one fret down from normal, pre-bend the string 1/4-step, strike it, and quickly bend it another 1/4-step to the given note.